# Prison just sitting there

Tags: prison-architect

I've been developing a prison for a while, and something weird is going on: Nothing is happening!

For the first day or so, I kept getting `TODO: Escort Prisoner to Cell` in the Tasks list, but the guards would just move prisoners around their cells. That finally stopped, but now they don't do *anything*. The prisoners' needs just keep growing & growing, and they're not doing anything to decrease them. At `Eat` and `Freetime`, they just wander around their cells. The cooks don't prepare food; it's like they're on strike or something. Pretty soon I'm probably going to have a riot! I've tried messing with the Deployment tab & making a new prison, bit neither really did anything.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: A screenshot of your prison would help a lot in figuring out what's wrong. To me, it sounds like your prisoners just can't get to where they need. Possibly because of security levels.

Comment: Maybe one of the doors is blocked, something's blocking, try openning the deployment tab (( If you've researched it )). It will show you the areas that have "NO ACEESS" area, try to look for the source of the block.

Comment: Screenshot will be up in a few hours; I won't have access for a while.

Comment: I have had this before, I'm pretty sure it's a bug. Prisoner stuck in handcuffs forever, even past his release time.

Comment: @Joseph I checked that. No luck.  :/

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the 'jobs' tab?

Comment: That may be the best of titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the best way to fix this is to make a new prison. For the first few days-I am currently on game day 9-it was pretty much the same problem. I'm thinking that I didn't have enough free guards or maybe that it was just a bug. Anyway, the problem seems to have solved itself; Prisoners go to the Shower, Canteen, & Yard, the Guards escort them there, food is prepared, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your problem appears to be that your Canteen is not designated as a Canteen room type, so as far as the game is concerned you have a big room with tables benches and serving tables next to the kitchen, but no Canteen. The cooks aren't cooking anything because they don't have a Canteen to cook for. Likewise the inmates are not eating because they don't have a Canteen to get food from.

As for them not going to the Yard, Showers, Common Room, etc during free time make sure that there is a path from their cells to those areas that does not require them to go through Staff Only areas. If they have to go through Staff Only areas they need to wait for a guard to escort them, if the free-time period is too short that might not happen before the period is over.

Comment: Regarding pathing issues: I noticed that the gates to the yard use automatic door-openers. Are these connected to a door control with a guard sitting at it? Do they have power? When the door openers have no control, the door will be completely unoperative.